# Solve for the base of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, median, centroid

The area of an isosceles triangle is $S$ and the angle between the medians to the legs, facing the base, is $\alpha$. Find the base of the triangle.

> $2\sqrt{\dfrac{S\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}{3}}.$

[image]

Let $CH$ be the third median of the triangle. The point $M$ lies on $CH$ because the triangle is isosceles, so in $\triangle ABM,$ $MH$ is a median and an altitude so it's an isosceles triangle. Then $\measuredangle AMH=\measuredangle BMH=\dfrac{\alpha}{2}.$ I have studied only trig functions of an acute angle. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centroid divides the median into the ratio $2:1$ where the $2$ is the side of the angle it is coming from and $1$ is the side of the centroid where the median meets the side. That makes $CM:MH=2:1 \implies MH= \dfrac13 CH \implies CH = 3 MH$.

In $\triangle AHM$ you have $\dfrac{AH}{MH}=\tan\left( \dfrac{\alpha}2 \right) $, $AB=2AH$ and the base-height formula for $S$.

Comment: The OP looked for an hint :)

Comment: edited it -- :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $MH = \frac1{3}CH$ so $AH/MH =\frac{3AB}{2CH}$. Now make use of the standard formula for the area and compare that with this equation. I'm sure you will find the answer.